# hooks in react error in context or dependency error can anyone help me to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, react-context

Failed to compile.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:4)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  `|  |   return ( |     <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData, updateDisplayPicture }}> |       {children} |     </UserContext.Provider>`
  ERROR in ../src/context/UserContext.jsx 21:4
  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:4)
  File was processed with these loaders:
- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
  Failed to compile.

`your text`